# Get id or mac address of the computer an app was built from?

Tags: android, ios

I am wondering if its possible to get the id or mac address of the computer that an ios or android app was built from programatically, without saving this to a file manually?

If this is possible i am looking for a solution for ios and android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible - once the app is compiled/build, there's no reference back to the original computer, on which the app was built.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to Android, no, the MAC address of the developer's computer is not baked into the APK.